# Rails deploy fails with `Unable to load application: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fiber`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-7

**TLDR;** I'm running a Rails app on Heroku. I have staging & production environments, set up as 2 apps in a pipeline. As the heroku stack heroku-18 has reached EOL, I'm in the process of upgrading the app to heroku-22. Upgrading staging worked perfectly fine, but on production I'm getting the following error: `Unable to load application: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fiber`

Note that my app is set up with 2 processes:

- web.1: web server running rails with puma
- worker.1: worker running sidekiq

Both processes crash every time I attempt to deploy. web.1:

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -p 11167`
app[web.1]: [2] Puma starting in cluster mode...
app[web.1]: [2] * Puma version: 6.2.2 (ruby 3.2.2-p53) ("Speaking of Now")
app[web.1]: [2] *  Min threads: 5
app[web.1]: [2] *  Max threads: 5
app[web.1]: [2] *  Environment: production
app[web.1]: [2] *   Master PID: 2
app[web.1]: [2] *      Workers: 2
app[web.1]: [2] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
app[web.1]: [2] * Preloading application
app[web.1]: [2] ! Unable to load application: LoadError: cannot load such file -- fiber
app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/puma)
app[web.1]: <internal:/app/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- fiber (LoadError)
app[web.1]: from <internal:/app/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.8/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.3/lib/action_view/renderer/streaming_template_renderer.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

And worker.1:

```
heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec sidekiq`
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
app[worker.1]: 2 TID-398 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.0.2 with redis options {:url=>"REDACTED", :ssl_params=>{:verify_mode=>0}}
app[worker.1]: bundler: failed to load command: sidekiq (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/sidekiq)
app[worker.1]: <internal:/app/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- fiber (LoadError)
app[worker.1]: from <internal:/app/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
app[worker.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.8/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
app[worker.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.3/lib/action_view/renderer/streaming_template_renderer.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

Environment details:

- ruby 3.2.2
- rails 7.0.4.3
- puma 6.2.2
- sidekiq 4.0.2  (haven't gotten around to upgrading this one but shouldn't affect web.1)
- Staging and production environments are very similar. They use the same gems except for newrelic_rpm (production only), which isn't anywhere in the crash stack trace. They have almost identical resources in heroku in terms of dynos and db types and so on.

The fact that both processes are crashing makes me think there's something wrong that is unrelated to the puma or sidekiq configurations. The fact that both run fine on staging has me baffled.

I first upgrading the staging environment using the heroku CLI to set the stack to heroku-22, and then deploying the latest version of the codebase (this included the new ruby version, new rails version, and may other gem and code updates). Then, I tried the following (rolling back to last working version after every deploy attempt ended in crash):

- Promoting the staging app to production (a heroku pipeline feature).
- Upgrading production stack from CLI, then deploying manually (not using pipeline).
- Contacting Heroku customer support.
- Setting HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 (suggested by Heroku CS), which did not produce any additional messages.
- Restarting dynos right after a failed deploy.
- Scaling dynos to 0, then deploying, then scaling back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is caused by using the version 9.2.2 of the `newrelic_rpm` gem.
Updating the Gemfile to `gem 'newrelic_rpm', '< 9.0'` results in installing v8.16.0 and the app loads correctly (and the NewRelic integration works as expected).

It is still unclear why v9.2.2 crashes. I have logged an issue [here](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/issues/2001) and may post a new version of this question that is specific to the circumstances of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**
Writing this question helped me realize the newrelic_rpm gem was installed only in production. I initially didn't suspect it would be related to the crash, but I tried commenting it out in my Gemfile and the app now correctly deploys to production!

This is not a full answer as I don't know why newrelic_rpm is crashing (I have reviewed the `newrelic.yml` config file and it pretty much matches the recommended one). But at least it gives me a path to continue debugging.

I plan on leaving the current version deployed to production as is (without newrelic), and deploying to staging a version that *does* use newrelic to see if I can repro the crash there and continue testing.

Lesson of the day: Keep your environments as similar as possible.